# In Dynamics CRM, how can I stop a user from entering more than 4 "Yes"s in a grid?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In my Dynamics CRM Opportunity form, I've added a Sales Quota Distribution Grid.  If more than four Yes's have been entered in the entire grid, I want a warning message (or something similar) to be shown.  For example, lets say record "A" t has 4 fields marked "Yes".  Record "B" account has zero.  If I change one the distributions next to record "B", I want the warning message to appear.
How can I do this?  If it is not possible to create a warning message for this situation, what are my options?

Update: I am working on a JavaScript event to get this to run.  Please see code below.  It is not yet working, and I could use some help debugging.

```
function getTotalYesCount(executionContext) {
   var formContext == executionContext.getFormContext();
   var allRows == null;
   var attributeColl == null;
   var idqualifyyescount;
   var sowbomyescount;
   var scopeyescount;
   var closeyescount;
   try {
       //get rows - use the getControl method and pass the grid name.
       allRows == gridContext.getGrid().getRows();
       //loop through rows and get the attribute collection
       allRows.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
           //get the attribute Collection
           attributeColl == row.data.entity.attributes;
               switch (att.getName()) {
                   case "new_idqualify":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           idqualifyyescount == idqualifyyescount +1;
                   case "new_sowbom":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           sowbomyescount == sowbomyescount +1;
                       }
                   case "new_scope":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           scopeyescount == scopeyescount +1;
                       }
                   case "new_close":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           closeyescount == closeyescount +1;
                       }
                       }
                       if ((idqualifyyescount + sowbomyescount + scopeyescount +closeyescount) > 4) {                          
                           Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("More than 4 Yes's have been entered in the Sales Quota Distribution.");
                       }                       
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: question: When you say Record "A" you mean opportunity Record or you mean Record for Sales quotation distribution Grid.
Also does your sales quotation distribution Grid Record has 4 fields with (YES/NO) or each record has 1 field and alltogether 4 records combined if YES then error?
Question is bit confusing.

Comment: @AnkUser, Apologies for the delay.  Record "A" meaning the record in the Sales Quota Distribution grid.  Each sales quota distribution record has 4 "yes/no" option fields.
Thanks, and hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will do the following

1. Create Plugin
2. Trigger, Entity: Sales Quota Distribution
3. Fields, Yes/No fields (4)
4. Plugin Message: Create,Update(status changes and fields change),delete
5. Then I will check when creating or updating record of sales quota if opp is filled and if for the same opp record there are already 4 yes/no been filled then throw exception

I chose plugin as it is server side, so that no matter where you create a record (import, UI create, Interface) your plugin will fire and check the condition

Comment: thank you. Would a JavaScript event work as well?  That is what I've been working on, but cannot get it to run properly.  Are you able to help with this?  If yes, please see my updated post above with code added for reference.  Thank you!!